# What is the correct 'scrapy' way to capture the output of multiple spiders into a single output file / variable?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and trying to make sense of how I output data post-scraping. I've read through some documentation and I'm struggling to make much sense of it and the documentation that is available is a little vague for my use case.

Essentially, I have around nine spiders that I kick off at the same time to scrape certain information from given websites. I initiate the crawl as follows:

```
from scrapy.utils import project
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

# Initialise a crawler
crawl_process = CrawlerProcess(project.get_project_settings())

# Locate and iterate through the spiders
for spider in (x for x in crawl_process.spider_loader.list()):
    crawl_process.crawl(spider)

# Kick it off
crawl_process.start()
```

The output of these spiders is a single dict for each (if there is a match), similar to the following:

```
yield {
    'Retailer': 'Amazon',
    'Item': 'Product Example',
    'Price': '£62.50',
    'URL': 'URL'
}
```

I would like to avoid writing to disk as much as possible as this script will be running on my Raspberry Pi's SD card, so writing to tens of files at a time every two or so minutes wouldn't be ideal.

**My Requirements:**

I would like to be able to find a way to gather the data in memory until all of the spiders have finished, and then I need to be able to create a list of dicts for comparison and finally output to a single json file. Is this at all possible? I'm really scratching my head with it.

If not possible, I'd be really interested in opinions on the correct way to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody else who may come across this, I found another answer in StackOverflow comments that monitors the `items_scraped` signal which allows you to interact with each item as you wish.

So my process is to set each spider crawling and then add the results from each spider to a list and returning it to my process queue once the spiders are finished.

```
results = []

# Method called every time item_passed signal is received
def crawler_results(signal, sender, item, response, spider):
    results.append(item)

# Connect to item_passed signal
dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_scraped)

# Initialise a crawler
crawl_process = CrawlerProcess(project.get_project_settings())

# Locate and iterate through the spiders
for spider in (x for x in crawl_process.spider_loader.list()):
    crawl_process.crawl(spider)

# Kick it off
crawl_process.start()

# Output results to queue
queue.put(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing [Scrapy Pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) + [MongoDB Cloud](https://mongodb.com/cloud) is a great option. Utilize the pipeline for any logic, and write what you need to MongoDB.

You can also just add everything to MongoDB and write all logic using [Pymongo](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) with a few simple scripts.

Pipeline for option 2 would look something like:

```
import pymongo
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

class MongoPipeline:

  collection_name = 'scrapy_items'


  def open_spider(self, spider):
      self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(os.environ.get("MONGO_DB_CONNECTION_STRING"))
      self.db = self.client["db name"]

  def close_spider(self, spider):
      self.client.close()

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
      self.db[self.collection_name].insert_one(ItemAdapter(item).asdict())
      return item
```

MongoDB Cloud lowest tier is free and would likely be able to handle your data volume for the lifetime of the project (considering you're using a rasp pi).

Answer (score 1):

You can accumulate your items inside class variable and write it to disk at the end:

```
import json
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter

class CustomPipeline:

  data = []

  def close_spider(self, spider):
      # write your self.data to disk here

  def process_item(self, item, spider):
      self.data.append(ItemAdapter(item).asdict())
      return item
```